# Summarise values in multidimensional array with condition in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, array-sum

I have the following table in mysql

| e_id | p_id | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87 | 1019 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 87 | 1019 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 87 | 1020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 87 | 1021 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 87 | 1021 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 87 | 1021 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 89 | 1020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 89 | 1022 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 89 | 1022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I want to sum rows where e_id and p_id are equal. So the result should be like this:

| e_id | p_id | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87 | 1019 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 87 | 1020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 87 | 1021 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 89 | 1020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 89 | 1022 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I'm not sure if I can do that in mysql, probably only in php.
After fetch I got the following array in php

```
$schedules[]= array('employee' => $e_id, 'project' => $p_id, 'weeks' => $weeks);


$e_id = fetched e_id from table
$p_id = fetched p_id from table
$weeks = fetched array of w1..w4 from table
```

How would I do it? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `group by` on two columns. It should be like this:

```sql
SELECT
    e_id,
    p_id,
    SUM(w1) as w1,
    SUM(w2) as w2,
    SUM(w3) as w3,
    SUM(w4) as w4
FROM schedule
GROUP BY e_id, p_id
```

Answer (score 1):

select sum(w1) as w1,xxxxxxxxx from table_name group by e_id, p_id